# Opencart: Pre-Populate Paypal State Field With Australian States

Tags: paypal, opencart

Having some issues with opencart 1.5.5.1 and paypal standard. I'm using Paypal.com.au (In Australia) When I started there was no telephone and no state being passed from opencart to paypal. The rest of the fields (address, email, name) were all pre-populated. So I went in to the paypayl standard code and added this to the controller:

```
$this->data['night_phone_b'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['telephone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

and this to the tpl file:

```
<input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="<?php echo $night_phone_b; ?>" />
```

That worked for the phone, however, no matter what I try for the state, I can't get it to work. I looked at doing something like this:

```
$this->data['state'] = html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_zone_code'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

and the same as above but replacing `['payment_zone_code']` with `['payment_zone_id']` and `['zone_id']`

and in the tpl file:

```
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>" />
```

Anyway, I am stumped on getting the state passed over to paypal.

*EDIT* Checked here at paypal's Australian site: https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside
They don't offer any help on the issue either, all examples are for US states: "State (Must be 2 character official abbreviation)" with no help on 3 character abbreviations. Still waiting for a reply from them also

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can pass an Australian state with it's full name (the value on the Paypal buyer details select form, not the visible content)

This feels like a bit of a dodgy fix but it worked for me. Hopefully Paypal won't change anything though...

```
    $states['ACT'] = "Australian Capital Territory";
$states['NSW'] = "New South Wales";
$states['NT'] = "Northern Territory";
$states['QLD'] = "Queensland";
$states['SA'] = "South Australia";
$states['TAS'] = "Tasmania";
$states['VIC'] = "Victoria";
$states['WA'] = "Western Australia";
```

Then pass 'billing_region' instead of state as part of your form...

```
'billing_region' => $state[$fdata['u_state']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `iso_code_2` property of the concrete country? The `country` table is defined like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `oc_country` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `iso_code_2` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `iso_code_3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `address_format` text NOT NULL,
  `postcode_required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`)
)
```

The column `iso_code_2` contains the desired 2-character ISO country code.

In Your case when processing PayPal request You should be able to retrieve the payment address and it's country code (3-character ISO code) or ID - using this **unique** value (either it is `iso_code_3` or `country_id`) You should be able to find concrete country entry and obtain the desired `iso_code_2` value that You would then pass to the PayPal.

**EDIT:**

Should it be the states code, You can obtain that by using the known payment's address **`zone_id`**. One problem though - the codes for Australian states are not only 2 characters long:

```
Australian Capital Territory -> ACT
New South Wales              -> NSW
Northern Territory           -> NT
Queensland                   -> QLD
South Australia              -> SA
Tasmania                     -> TAS
Victoria                     -> VIC
Western Australia            -> WA
```

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_territories_of_Australia#States_and_territories), nor the states's abbreviation nor the ISO codes are only 2 characters long thus maybe You could try to send also the 3-characters codes and let the rest on PayPal (maybe the description is just incorrect and You are able to use 3-char. codes).

Comment: I changed my title to more clearly describe my problem. I mean the states in Australia not the state of Australia. (Victoria, Queensland, New South Wales, and so on).

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Yup, I have tried this. The state codes are held in payment_zone_code. I have tried passing that variable but with no success. I have gone into the database and changed the zone_id (the full name) to match the zone_code (abbreviation), So Queensland ->QLD, then pass that to paypal with payment_zone_id, but got no results either. Thanks for the ideas though.